# recursive assert on collection

Tags: .net, collections, nunit, assert

I would like a test like this one:

```
[Test]
    public void TestCollectionAssert ()
    {
        var a1 = new [] { new [] { "a" } };
        var a2 = new [] { new [] { "a" } };

        Assert.AreNotEqual (a1, a2);
        //CollectionAssert.AreEqual (a1, a2);
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent (a1, a2);
    }
```

to pass.
My real case is more complicated, but solving this one in a generic way will do.
Any ideas?

Comment: Should they be equal or not? Is position in the array relevant?

Comment: Well, they are equal, so I expect AreEquivalent to be true.

Comment: Well, I know why it doesn't work. However I am looking for some generic solution to the problem. Well, I _was_ looking for it. I solved the problem "locally" by implementing a special comparer, but when my collection types change, I will need to modify the comparer... So I hope someone comes up with a good solution :)

Answer (score 3):

**There's a useful LINQ operator called [`SequenceEqual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495305.aspx) which compares two sequences for equality.** `SequenceEqual()` walks through any two `IEnumerable<>` sequences and verifies that they have the same number of elements and that elements at the same index are equal (using the default equality comparer). However, since you have nested collections, you need to extend the concept of equality to apply to them as well. Fortunately, there's an overload that allows you supply your own `IEqualityComparer<>` object.

Since it's awkward to constantly have to define a class to provide equality semantics, I've written a generic extension that allows you to use a delegate instead. Let's look at the code:

```
public static class ComparerExt
{
    private class GenericComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, T, bool> m_EqualityFunc;

        public GenericComparer( Func<T,T,bool> compareFunc )
        {
            m_EqualityFunc = compareFunc;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return m_EqualityFunc(x, y);
        }
    }

    // converts a delegate into an IComparer
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> AreEqual<T>( Func<T,T,bool> compareFunc )
    {
        compareFunc.ThrowIfNull("compareFunc");

        return new GenericComparer<T>(compareFunc);
    }
}
```

**Now, we can compare two sequences easily enough:**

```
Assert.IsTrue( 
   // check that outer sequences are equivalent...
   a1.SequenceEqual( a2,
                     // define equality as inner sequences being equal... 
                     ComparerExt.AreEqual( (a,b) => a.SequenceEqual(b) ) );
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, but it still works only for 1-level nested collections, so not really a generic solution :) And in my real case I have KeyValuePair<string,string[]>[] and your way in solving the issue seems too complicated

Comment: @wysek: So when you say you're looking for a *generic solution*, do you mean for any level of nesting? That wasn't clear in you question. Let us know if that's the case.

Comment: I have rather been looking for a tool already existing... But seems there is none. I have implemented my own non-generic comparer for this, however thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method like the one below.

```
public class AssertExtension
{
    public bool AreSimilar<T>(this CollectionAssert, IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is of course how to compare this two lists. I would suggest to step through the elements of the one list and try to remove them from the other. If there is a problem while doing this or at the end there are objects left they are not similar.

Comment: What you suggest will modify one of the lists, I consider this unacceptable. Also, removing an item will call Equals() anyway, and it won't work like I want it to :)

Comment: You could avoid to modify one of the lists by making a copy of it, but you're right, the solution isn't very comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but somebody just posted a link on the nunit-discuss list, so I'll answer.

NUnit is designed to report the two lists as equal. That's just how it works. The Assert.NotEqual should in fact fail.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented following method, to compare the elements recursively.
It worked so far for all my test cases, I could miss an edge case.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Compares two enumerables recursively.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">IEnumerable</param>
    /// <param name="right">IEnumerable</param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool SequenceEqual(this IEnumerable left, IEnumerable right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, left))
        {
            return false;
        }


        if (left.GetType() != right.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var leftEnumerator = left.GetEnumerator();
        var rightEnumerator = right.GetEnumerator();

        while (leftEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!rightEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(leftEnumerator.Current.GetType()))
            {
                if (!typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(rightEnumerator.Current.GetType()))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (!SequenceEqual((IEnumerable)leftEnumerator.Current, (IEnumerable)rightEnumerator.Current))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Equals(leftEnumerator.Current, rightEnumerator.Current))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (rightEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```