# CollectionAssert - asserting collections of collections

Tags: c#, nunit, assert

I have the following:

```
internal class Payments
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string[] members = new string[] {
            "date = " + date,
            "amount = " + amount,
            "currency = " + currency,
        };

        return string.Join( ", ", members );
    }
}
```

...

```
internal class Customer
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string ip_address { get; set; }
    public List<Payments> payments { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string[] members = new string[] {
            "id = " + id,
            "first_name = " + first_name,
            "last_name = " + last_name,
            "email = " + email,
            "country = " + country,
            "ip_address = " + ip_address,
            "payments = <" + payments.ToString() + ">",
        };

        return string.Join( ", ", members );
    }
}
```

But the following fails:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(
    customersListA,
    customersListB,
    typeof(List<Customer>).ToString()
    );
```

I suspect it is because `Payments` is a `List`, so it only asserts against the pointer. Is there a way to have NUnit assert the contents of `List<Payments>` instead of the pointer?

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239927/nunit-nested-collection-comparison), but one of the writers of NUnit said [that particular problem was fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20153537/2687324).

Note: for now, because I have overridden `ToString()`, I am doing:

```
Assert.AreEqual(
    customers.OrderBy( c => c.id ).ToString(),
    _allData.OrderBy( c => c.id ).ToString(),
    typeof( List<Customer> ).ToString()
    );
```

Comment: You need to implement some kind of "deep" equivalence check for this comparison to succeed, such as override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and/or implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface. Also, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the third argument `typeof...`? The third argument is only a formatter for the test failure output.

Comment: Just want to call out the type when the assert fails.