# How to compare sets that are nested in dictionaries with NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit, hashset

In newer versions of NUnit, it is apparently possible to compare nested collections, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20153537/5133585) said. However, it seems like this does not work so well with nested `HashSet`s. Consider:

```
var a1 = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> { 
    { "a", new() { "b", "c" } },
    { "b", new() { "c" } },
    { "c", new() { } },
};
var a2 = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> { 
    { "c", new() { } },
    { "a", new() { "b", "c" } },
    { "b", new() { "c" } },
};
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a1, a2);
```

This passes, but if I change the order in which I add values to the sets a little bit (or do anything that changes the iteration order of one of the sets):

```
var a1 = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> { 
    { "a", new() { "b", "c" } },
    { "b", new() { "c" } },
    { "c", new() { } },
};
var a2 = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> { 
    { "c", new() { } },
    { "a", new() { "c", "b" } },
    { "b", new() { "c" } },
};
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a1, a2);
```

I expected it to still pass because a `HashSet` is unordered, but the test fails:

```
  ----> NUnit.Framework.AssertionException :   Expected and actual are both <System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]]> with 3 elements
  Values differ at index [0]
  String lengths are both 1. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "b"
  But was:  "c"
  -----------^
```

It seems like NUnit is not aware that `HashSet` is unordered, but *is* aware that a `Dictionary` is unordered.

So I think I need to use `HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer()` somewhere. I know I can specify the equality comparer to use for a comparison with `Using`:

```
Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(b).Using(someEqualityComparer));
```

But I am trying to provide it for the comparison of the *nested* sets. How would I do that?

To avoid being an XY problem: The dictionary in my real code actually represents the edges of a control flow graph. It's actually a `Dictionary<BasicBlock, HashSet<BasicBlock>>`.

Comment: Its treating the `HashSet` as an *enumerable* where order matters, as you have likely guessed. If you changed `HashSet` to a `SortedSet` (E.g `Dictionary<string, SortedSet<string>`) you would likely get the result you'd expect. however, may not be suitable for what you want.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for reminding me that `SortedSet` exists! In my case, I _can_ write an `IComparer` for `BasicBlock`, so I think it is possible to use a `SortedSet`. I am still open to more general solutions though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit isn't exactly "aware" that dictionaries are unordered. However, it does have special code for testing Dictionary equality, as described [on this page](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/EqualConstraint.html). You'll note that the page doesn't say anything about Hashsets, which get no special treatment.

As you suggested, the simplest way to deal with Hashsets in your example is to define your own comparer. I suggest defining one, which implements, `IEqualityComparer<Hashset>`. This will automatically take care of the nesting problem, since NUnit will only use that comparer when it reaches the nested Hashsets.

If necessary, you can repeat `Using` to create multiple comparers for different types. However, from what you have said, that doesn't seem to be necessary in this case.

Comment: Oh! So even though I'm saying `Is.EqualTo(someDictionary)`, I can still say `.Using(someHashSetEqualityComparer)`, and it will only use that equality comparer when comparing the nested sets? I'm surprised that `Using` is so smart. Is this documented anywhere? I wonder why I couldn't find anything on this...

Comment: It's documented on the page I referenced, although possibly not explained very clearly. Note that this will only work if your comparer implements `IEqualityComparer<HashSet>`. NUnit uses the generic param to decide when to apply it. Fair warning: I wrote the code and I know it worked (was tested) but I don't know if anything has changed since I worked on NUnit.